# Order by is not working in MVC Linq query

Tags: linq

For some reason order by is not working my linq query. Could anyone please help me to find what I am doing wrong here. Here is my code -

```
var q = (from a in db.Alerts
                 join ap in db.AlertParks on a.AlertId equals ap.AlertId
                 join p in db.Parks on ap.parkId equals p.parkId
                 where a.EndDate > DateTime.Now
                 orderby p.Name ascending
                 select new { a.Title, a.Description, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, a.AlertId, p.Name, a.alertType.IconUrl })
                 .OrderBy(p=>p.Name)
                .Concat(from a in db.Alerts
                        join l in db.Locations on a.AlertId equals l.AlertId
                        where a.EndDate > DateTime.Now
                        select new { a.Title, a.Description, l.Latitude, l.Longitude, a.AlertId, l.Name, a.alertType.IconUrl })
                        .OrderBy(l=>l.Name);
```

it is returning -

```
      [
    {
    "Title": "Road closed due to bush fire in Albany",
    "Description": "what should i write here. I need to fill this at least 100 characters.",
    "Latitude": -31.9699993134,
    "Longitude": 116.0599975586,
    "AlertId": "349dcec1-3d06-49b6-9fcf-0430712f59ef",
    "Name": "Bibbulmun Track Darling Range",
    "IconUrl": "~/media/movierental.png"
    },
    {
    "Title": "This is a test alert to see how it works.",
    "Description": "some description text",
    "Latitude": -33.5099983215,
    "Longitude": 123.3600006104,
    "AlertId": "b4b3018e-6f70-4dec-a62c-ea402bb0075e",
    "Name": "Cape Arid",
    "IconUrl": "~/media/movierental.png"
    },
    {
    "Title": "This is a test alert to see how it works.",
    "Description": "fsdf sfsdfsdfsd",
    "Latitude": -32.02,
    "Longitude": 115.91,
    "AlertId": "b4b3018e-6f70-4dec-a62c-ea402bb0075e",
    "Name": "Canning River",
    "IconUrl": "~/media/movierental.png"
    },
    {
    "Title": "fdsfs ",
    "Description": "fds ",
    "Latitude": -30.04,
    "Longitude": 115.58,
    "AlertId": "cc7c18a5-30f0-4dad-b357-29bd29e828fc",
    "Name": "Alexander Morrison",
    "IconUrl": "~/media/sauna.png"
    },
    {
    "Title": "fdsfs ",
    "Description": "fds ",
    "Latitude": -31.94,
    "Longitude": 116.13,
    "AlertId": "cc7c18a5-30f0-4dad-b357-29bd29e828fc",
    "Name": "Beelu",
    "IconUrl": "~/media/sauna.png"
    },
    {
    "Title": "fdsfs ",
    "Description": "fds ",
    "Latitude": -33.5099983215,
    "Longitude": 123.3600006104,
    "AlertId": "cc7c18a5-30f0-4dad-b357-29bd29e828fc",
    "Name": "Cape Arid",
    "IconUrl": "~/media/sauna.png"
    }]
```

Comment: Not related, but the `orderby p.Name ascending` and `.OrderBy(p=>p.Name)` are not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, here is the modified code -

```
var q = (from a in db.Alerts
                 join ap in db.AlertParks on a.AlertId equals ap.AlertId
                 join p in db.Parks on ap.parkId equals p.parkId
                // orderby p.Name
                 where a.EndDate<=DateTime.Now
                 select new { a.Title, a.Description, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, a.AlertId, p.Name, a.alertType.IconUrl })
                 .Concat(from a in db.Alerts
                        join l in db.Locations on a.AlertId equals l.AlertId
                        where a.EndDate <= DateTime.Now
                        select new { a.Title, a.Description, l.Latitude, l.Longitude, a.AlertId, l.Name, a.alertType.IconUrl })
                        .OrderBy(a=>a.Name);
```